# Python callback/script returned the following error

Tags: python, vpn

I have desktop running Ubuntu 16.4. It is mainly used for the home network server. One of the functions is a media center running Kodi and the TV Headend PVR backend. The bedroom unit is a Raspberry Pi running Kodi. They both are configured to use a VPN. Lately I have seen poor performance with some of the functions. I am trying to narrow down the issue. Below is a portion of the Kodi log.

```
16:10:30.440 T:140586069743360   ERROR: EXCEPTION Thrown (PythonToCppException) : -->Python callback/script returned the following error<--
                                         - NOTE: IGNORING THIS CAN LEAD TO MEMORY LEAKS!
                                        Error Type: <class 'socket.error'>
                                        Error Contents: [Errno 98] Address already in use
                                        Traceback (most recent call last):
                                          File "/home/mycomputer/.kodi/addons/plugin.video.SportsDevil/service/streamlink_proxy.py", line 367, in <module>
                                            httpd = server_class((HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER), MyHandler)
                                          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 417, in __init__
                                            self.server_bind()
                                          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 108, in server_bind
                                            SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
                                          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 431, in server_bind
                                            self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
                                          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
                                            return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
                                        error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
                                        -->End of Python script error report<--
```

I have basic skills with Ubuntu, no real knowledge of python. Can anyone tell me about the python error, or better yet, how to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

This is the relevant line:

```
[Errno 98] Address already in use
```

This means that whatever port Python is trying to bind to is already in use.  You need to configure Kodi to use a *different* port for listening on an interface, because you can't bind to the same port twice (in a default standard Ubuntu setup)

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I will search for instructions on configuring Kodi to use a different port for listening on an interface. If you have a link to such instruction, or any instruction on how to configure Kodi to use a different port for listening, that would be incredibly helpful.